# Binding angular scope inside a fancybox not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fancybox, angularjs-directive

I created an angular directive to work with fancybox and it partially works.

Check out the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4LUf2QKCT4tDxlTs2RzW?p=preview)

The data binding works ok, if I change a variable outside the fancybox and then open the fancybox it will show inside the fancybox. Same happens if the var is changed from inside the fancybox, it will reflect changes outside the box.

The problem is that variables are not getting updated if they are inside the fancybox using the brackets `{{ }}`. (look at example 3 and 4 in the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4LUf2QKCT4tDxlTs2RzW?p=preview)).

For example, if you open example #3, change the input, close the box and reopen the box, then you will see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what reason is but it works by changing:

```
<pre>{{foo}}</pre>
```

To

```
<pre ng-bind="foo"></pre>
```

I tried wrapping your `$compile` in `$timeout` to see if that made a difference also before trying `ng-bind`

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/7nttsqJcxncfCFeQKcco?p=preview)

Comment: Still doesn't work. Look at example #4 in the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4LUf2QKCT4tDxlTs2RzW?p=preview), I added an `ngRepeat` list, and using `ngBind` instead of the brackets still doesn't update the list inside the box, only after closing and reopening the box.